# Replace values in data frame with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I get this data frame:

```
               Item ................. 
0              Banana (From Spain)... 
1              Chocolate ............ 
2              Apple (From USA) ..... 
               ............
```

And I want change all Item's names by removing the parenthesis, getting finally

```
               Item ................. 
0              Banana ............... 
1              Chocolate ............ 
2              Apple ................ 
               ............
```

I thought, I should use replace but there are too much data so I'm thinking in use something like

```
import re

    for i in dataframe.index:
       if bool(re.search('.*\(.*\).*', dataframe.iloc[i]["Item"])):
          dataframe.ix[i,"Item"] = dataframe.iloc[i]["Item"].split(" (")[0]
```

But I'm not sure if is the most efficient way.

Comment: try this `df.Item = df.Item.str.replace('\([^\)]*\)', '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
df.Item = df.Item.apply(lambda x: x.split(" (")[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) by `regex` with [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) if need remove last whitespaces:

```
df.Item = df.Item.str.replace(r"\(.*\)","").str.strip()
print (df)
        Item
0     Banana
1  Chocolate
2      Apple
```

Another simplier solution with [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df.Item = df.Item.str.split(' \(').str[0]
print (df)
        Item
0     Banana
1  Chocolate
2      Apple
```